# Getting websocket session

Tags: go, websocket

My idea is as follows.

When connection from client-side (browser) is requested, server generates random **token** on websocket upgrade request and sends it via HTTP Set-Cookie header. Then, client authenticates via Challenge-Response authentication over websocket connection. On successful auth, server saves previously generated **token** in database for user. **token** cookie is needed to restore session, when user re-initiates websocket connection.

My question is, how can I temporarily store **token** on memory per connection (per user), so that I can access it later and save in database for that user? (sort of "request context").

Comment: Sounds like you can simply make this a local variable in the websocket handler.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I need cookies to restore session, in case when user re-initiates websocket connection.

Comment: @Peter but how can I make variable _per request_?

Comment: @Azamat A websocket application typically upgrades an HTTP request to the WebSocket protocol and then runs a loop reading and processing messages.  If you want to store state for the duration of the connection, then declare a variable outside of the loop.  If you want to store state for the duration of processing a message, then declare a variable inside the loop.  Please show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
// initialize an empty map
var Clients = make(map[*websocket.Conn]bool)
```

and then add the connection or token to the map like this

```
// upgrade connection to websocket and add it to the map
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
Clients[conn] = true
```